# Could not automate an ADB binary

Tags: android-studio

Anytime I launch my Android emulator on my Kali machine I get an error message saying "Could not automatically detect and ABD binary",what could be the cause and solution and also when I launch my Android studio and I try running my app in the initializing adb part it keeps loading without showing my Android emulator which I already created...Please any suggestions on how to solve this

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?